# vimのカラースキームに関して

Tags: bash, vim, wsl

deinでプラグインを入れてvimにカラースキームを設定してみたのですが、移動して戻ると文字以外の部分が赤くなります。
違うカラースキームで試したり、VMで違う環境を作って試してみましたが同じ現象が起きます。

ググってみても同じ現象の投稿が全くありません。

解決方法ご存知の方いましたら、大事なお時間を少し頂戴して、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

実行環境として、Windows の WSL を使用しています。

[image: 画像]

.dein.tomlの中身です。

```
 # clipboard                                                                      
  2 [[plugins]]
  3 repo = 'kana/vim-fakeclip'
  4
  5 [[plugins]]
  6 repo = 'w0ng/vim-hybrid'
```

以下は.vimrcの内容です。

```
" deinがインストールされるディレクトリの指定
let s:dein_dir = expand('~/.cache/dein') "<- dein によってプラグインがインストールされるディレクトリ
let s:dein_repo_dir = s:dein_dir . '/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim'

" deinがインストールされているかをチェック インストールされていなかったらdeinをダウンロードしてくる
if &runtimepath !~# '/dein.vim'
 if !isdirectory(s:dein_repo_dir)
 execute '!git clone https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim' s:dein_repo_dir
 endif
 execute 'set runtimepath^=' . fnamemodify(s:dein_repo_dir, ':p')
endif

" deinの起動
if dein#load_state(s:dein_dir)
 call dein#begin(s:dein_dir)

 " tomlファイル（使用するプラグインのリストが記述されているファイル）の場所を指定
 let g:rc_dir = expand('~/.vim/dein') "<- dein.toml dein_lazy.toml を読み込むディレクトリ
 let s:toml = g:rc_dir . '/dein.toml'
 " let s:lazy_toml = g:rc_dir . '/dein_lazy.toml' "<- dein_lazy.toml を使う場合はコメント解除

 " tomlファイルを読み込む
 call dein#load_toml(s:toml, {'lazy': 0})
 " call dein#load_toml(s:lazy_toml, {'lazy': 1}) "<- dein_lazy.toml を使う場合はコメント解除

 " 設定の終了
 call dein#end()
 call dein#save_state()
endif

" プラグインのインストールをチェック 未インストールのプラグインがあればインストールする
if dein#check_install()
 call dein#install()
endif

" 文字コードの指定
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=iso-2022-jp,euc-jp,sjis,utf-8
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac

" コピーペースト
map <c-y> "*yy
map <c-p> "*p

" 挿入モードでのカーソル移動
inoremap <c-j> <Down>
inoremap <c-k> <Up>
inoremap <c-b> <Left>
inoremap <c-l> <Right>

" 色設定
syntax enable 
set background=dark
colorscheme hybrid
set visualbell

"インデントを４にする
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

" 行番号の表示
set number
" 括弧
set showmatch

" バックスペースキーで削除できるものを指定
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" 挿入モード時に非点滅の縦棒タイプのカーソル
let &t_SI .= "\e[6 q"
" ノーマルモード時に非点滅のブロックタイプのカーソル
let &t_EI .= "\e[2 q"
" 置換モード時に非点滅の下線タイプのカーソル
let &t_SR .= "\e[4 q"
set cursorline

" <ステータスライン>
" ファイル名表示
set statusline=%F
" 変更チェック表示
set statusline+=%m
" 読み込み専用かどうか表示
set statusline+=%r
" ヘルプページなら[HELP]と表示
set statusline+=%h
" プレビューウインドウなら[Prevew]と表示
set statusline+=%w
" これ以降は右寄せ表示
set statusline+=%=
" file encoding
set statusline+=[ENC=%{&fileencoding}]
" 現在行数/全行数
set statusline+=[LOW=%l/%L]
" ステータスラインを常に表示(0:表示しない、1:2つ以上ウィンドウがある時だけ表示)
set laststatus=2
" ステータスラインの色 
highlight StatusLine   term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkGray ctermbg=LightGreen
```

Comment: 利用している端末エミュレータは何でしょうか?
また環境変数 TERM の値は何にしていますか?

Comment: 使っているのWindowsのWSLです。環境変数は確認したら、TERM=xterm-256color　ってなってました。

Comment: 移動して戻ると、というのはファイルを開いてから jk を押す、というような操作を表しているでしょうか? * ファイルを開く <- 色は通常
* j を押す <- 色は通常
* k を押す <- 真っ赤に染まる というような挙動だと解釈しましたが合っていますか?

Comment: ちょっと説明しずらいのですが、  ファイルを開く <- 色は通常
j を押す <- 色は通常　ある程度下にいく
k を押す <- 色は通常　ページ?が切り替わる（隠れていた行まで、移動する）と、移動した行だけ空白が赤くなる   <c-d>など押して、大きく移動すると、一気に赤くなる感じです。  分かりずらくてすいません。

Comment: 行末に半角スペースを２つ入れても、  改行されません。（汗

Comment: なるほど、再度描画すると赤くなるのですね。
vim の version は何でしょうか?

Comment: version 8.1.2292　です。

Comment: あと、設定されている dein.toml の中身も、(あまりに長大でなければ) 質問に追記してもらえると回答できる人が現われる可能性が上がるかもです

Comment: 親切にご対応していただき、ありがとうございます。

Comment: @takada コメント欄では改行が使えませんのでご注意ください。

Comment: ＠cubickさん　そうだったんですね。何で改行出来ないんだろうと不思議でした。。。　教えていただき、ありがとうございます。　スッキリしました。（笑

Answer (score 6, accepted):

手元でも再現出来ました。
みたところWindowsのコマンドプロンプトのバグっぽいです。

対策としては、

- [wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty) 等の別の(まともな)端末エミュレータを使う
- 標準のコンソール(コマンドプロンプト)を使うならば、以下の設定を .vimrc に追加する

```
set t_ut=
```

の二つが考えられます。

Comment: 手元で再現していただき、ありがとうございます。　　試しにset t_ut=を.vimrcに追加してみたところ、解決出来ました。　　端末エミュレータに関しては、勉強不足で、ちゃんと理解出来ていません。　　wslとコマンドプロンプトは違うものだと認識していました。　もっと勉強して、wsltty等を使えるようになりたいです。　　手元での再現の速さ、的確な対策のご指摘、尊敬致します。　いわもとさん忙しい中、ご教授いただき、本当にありがとうございます。